# Can I quickly move my node from my Windows box to a virtualbox Ubuntu guest by making the blockchain path a shared folder?

Tags: blockchain, ubuntu, blockchain-export

That's. That's pretty much it. I'm just wondering if I can do this and whether it'll work properly. Just shut down the Ubuntu guest, go into the VBox manager, make the folder with the extant blockchain files shared and mount it to Ubuntu's default localnode path, then go back into the virtual Ubuntu machine and start node setup with the blockchain already in place.

P.S.: I would just export/duplicate the files onto the virtual machine instead of linking them but the blockchain is already a good order of magnitude larger than my average size for entire *nix *hard drives*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're not going to be able to share a folder on Windows and mount it in a VirtualBox guest Ubuntu, using the blockchain from that mounted shared folder. This is because the blockchain file is memory mapped when opened and I'm pretty certain vboxsf (which is the kernel module that handles the share), doesn't support this.

You could create the share and copy/move the file(s) to a non-vboxsf mounted folder, just not *use* it from the mounted share. If space is your concern, start `monerod` from scratch on your VM with `--prune-blockchain`. That will give you a much smaller blockchain on disk.